# Linux TCP: high Send-Q on sender, zero Recv-Q on receiver

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

How can it be that:

1. There is a TCP socket between two machines
2. After some succesful bidirectional communications, sender application is stuck on writing to the socket and receiver on reading from it
3. `netstat` reports high Send-Q (a few megabytes) for the socket on the sender (and the value does not change even after a couple of hours of waiting)
4. `netstat` reports zero Recv-Q for the socket on the receiver
5. `tcpdump` reports that the only activity on the socket is a periodic (biminutely) ACK with no data from the sender and immediate ACK response with no data from the receiver

Why doesn't the sender machine attempt to send queued data to the receiver?

Comment: You didn't post any code, so there's not much to go on.  Try examining the contents of that periodic ACK (which is likely a TCP keepalive) for the current TCP window size.

Comment: Yes, it must be a TCP keepalive. Each time sender window size is 40822, receiver window size is 31883.

Comment: Smells like a bug on the receiver side not consuming all the bytes from the socket. But you didn't post any code, so there's no way of knowing.

Comment: I tested this hypothesis, but when receiver application fails to consume incoming data, Recv-Q on the receiver socket stays well above zero as expected. I have neither small nor reproducible test case, and I suspect the issue only happens when network temporarily loses some IP packets. I do not ask for help with the application code, since it does not seem at fault given that data sits in the sender kernel buffer, but for help with understanding seeming impossible Linux kernel state.

Comment: @OrivejDesh were you able to find the root cause of this?

Comment: @OrivejDesh I have the exact same issue. In my case there's an rsync daemon and a client, both running in different machines but in the same local network. The Send-Q of the sender (client) is stuck at some 300kB, while both queues in the server are 0 (as reported by ss or netstat). However there are TCP keepalives emitted periodically. And both rsync processes are stuck on a select() loop, trying to read from the socket.

Comment: This looks like a probable explanation: https://engineering.skroutz.gr/blog/uncovering-a-24-year-old-bug-in-the-linux-kernel/

Answer (score 2):

I my case, client was writing data in chunks of 8KB and server was trying to read 8KB and server would then write it to RAID0 disks. For uploading large files, I faced a similar situation and increasing the amount of data I was reading from socket on server side helped. I bumped up the size of internal buffer that was reading from socket to 1MB (from 8 kB) and it helped. I don't know for sure whether it was because of RAID or tcp but it could be another thing you might want to try out.

Answer (score 2):

This is more likely caused by other problem, but below *might* help if you haven't tried (these numbers are examples, find your own numbers):

1. Estimate your sender and receiver file system read/write speed as well as network speed, and set appropriate bandwidth limit in rsync:  ***--bwlimit=1024*** (1024 KBps)
2. If sender and receiver have dedicated NIC in this local network, do yourself a favor, increase MTU on these NICs: ***ifconfig eth1 mtu 65744***
3. Increase sender transmission queue length: ***ifconfig eth1 txqueuelen 4096***
4. Increase kernel send/receive memory: 
   add these to */etc/sysctl.conf* file
   ***net.core.wmem_max=16777216

   net.core.rmem_max=16777216

     net.ipv4.tcp_rmem=4096 262144 16777216

     net.ipv4.tcp_wmem=4096 262144 16777216***
   run *sysctl -p* afterwards.
5. If you rsync a very large file system, make sure fs.file-max is large enough,
   to check it: ***sysctl  fs.file-max***
   to increase it, add a line ***fs.file-max=327679***  to the file */etc/sysctl.conf*, 
   on your rsync user, run: ***ulimit -n 327679***

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem， maybe the `conntrack` have been delete in receiver side, check your
`/proc/net/nf_conntrack` file, if there is no information about this socket, then there is the problem

also see: [Connection Reset By Peer - with driver 2.8.0 and mongo 4.0.9 on a k8s cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56733622/connection-reset-by-peer-with-driver-2-8-0-and-mongo-4-0-9-on-a-k8s-cluster/57496563#57496563)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30853738)